# Odoo V10 - Order of execution of the views?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a big problem with my module. I wanted to uninstall it because I had a problem and then reinstall it. I found the original problem but now I have many other problems.
Whenever I try to install my module, I have an error of type -> ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: ...

I know that Odoo has a sense of XML writing or declaration. I have the impression that everything was in order. But I do not know what to do. Is there a particular order in the odoo manifesto? How can one successfully uninstall its Module to reinstall it properly?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Try by uncomment the xml file containing views from __manifest__, and then you can reinstall easely

Comment: Thank you it works!